# Base Number Systems Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need help with a number theory problem involving base number systems from Introduction to Number Theory by the Art of Problem Solving Solving. The problem is as follows: How many positive numerals can be written using a set of 5 total digits if each numeral is no more than 3 digits long? To me the question seems vague. I understand a numeral is any symbol in a number system that represents some numeric value; however, what number base is this 5 digit numeral being expressed in?

Comment: I guess the base-$4$-system is meant with its $5$ digits $0,1,2,3,4$. And leading zeros are probably not permitted.

Comment: The question makes sense in any base $≥5$.  You could, for instance, take the digits $0,1,6,7,8$ in base $10$ if you wanted.  Note:  since the condition says "no more than $3$ digits long", leading zeroes are permitted.  Base $5$ is certainly a good base to think about though.

Comment: @lulu For a counting argument, we can allow leading zeros (with the exception that we only have zeros, which would just be numeral $0$). But we can also count the $3$ digits , $2$ digits , one -  digit numerals seperately and this time without leading zeros. I agree that the answer is much easier and much more elegant if we consider also leading zeros.

Comment: @Peter  Yeah, I think allowing leading zeroes is the way to go.

Comment: @lulu This way, the answer is almost immediate, the other approach would be cumbersome. We only have to consider that $040$ , for example , marks the numeral $40$.

Comment: This all make sense, thank you, all of you. I was able to solve the problem.